# Can Eslint specify configuration under child package with monorepo

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

```
.eslintrc.json
│   ├── app1
│   └── app2
│       ├── .eslintrc.json
```

Running this command under app2 child package.

```
./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./src/ --config .eslintrc.json
```

And showing this error...

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.4.1

ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "@typescript-eslint" uniquely.

- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/index.js (loaded in "../../.eslintrc.json )...
```

why ESlint still trying to access ../../.eslintrc.json in the root folder?

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-configuration-files) (emphasis mine):

> The first way to use configuration files is via `.eslintrc.*` and `package.json` files. ESLint will automatically look for them in the directory of the file to be linted, **and in successive parent directories all the way up to the root directory of the filesystem** (unless `root: true` is specified).

So the reason why ESLint is accessing an ".eslintrc.json" file located in a parent folder is simply because that is the default behaviour. If not otherwise specified, ".eslintrc.*" files will inherit their settings from other ".eslintrc.*" files in their ancestor folders.

To prevent this behavior, set `"root": true` in the ".eslintrc.json" file inside "app2", and ESLint will no longer try to access "../../.eslintrc.json" or any other configuration files up in the directory structure.